# How do I align two span elements one to the left, the other one to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have two `<span>` elements:

```
<span style="margin-right:auto;">©2012 XYZ Corp. All Rights Reserved.</span>
<span style="margin-left:auto;">Built with <a href="http://www.wordpress.org/">Wordpress</a> and hosted by <a href="http://www.mediatemple.net/">(mt)</a> in California.</span>
```

I want the first `<span>` to be on the left of the page and the second `<span>` to be on the right side, regardless of page width (so I can't use fixed positioning).

What CSS can I use to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The css variable `float` is used to position your elements.

The options are:

```
float:left;
float:right;
float:none;
```

---

```
<span style="float:left;">©2012 XYZ Corp. All Rights Reserved.</span>

<span style="float:right;">Built with <a
```

Here is working example:

```html
<span style="float:left; color: red;">©2012 XYZ Corp. All Rights Reserved.</span>

<span style="float:right; color: blue;">Built for example</span>
```

Comment: floats don't contribute to the container height though, so it all collapses

Comment: @Triynko correct! When you're floating elements inside a container (parent element), the container will collapse, so to avoid that you have a couple of options. Google "clear fix" or simply just apply `overflow:hidden` to said container

Comment: yep that doesn't work I have a `footer` with a `div` and an `a` inside the div is a couple `p` and inside the `a` is the `span`