# Is there an Unicode character for justification?

Tags: html, unicode

I am working with a CMS that escapes HTML, so I was wondering if Unicode could be a solution. (This is to be used in a database field, which is then read and put in a `<p>` tag after being html-encoded.)

I am trying to achieve the justification of a text like in the image.
I am trying to send the 'text2' part of text to the extreme right of the line.

[image]

Comment: Float comes to mind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903979/align-2-span-one-left-and-the-other-right-inside-a-div https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303976/how-do-i-align-two-span-elements-one-to-the-left-the-other-one-to-the-right

Comment: Any HTML character I use is automatically escaped to &xxx; notation. That is the reason I can only use raw text.

Comment: No, but you can do it in css: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71391780/6266107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Unicode works at the character level where as Justification is to do with layout which is dependent on things such as page width and font / font size.

There are some things that layout will use Unicode for such as the [line break algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/), but the width of a character is highly dependent on the font, c.f. the difference in width of `i` between fixed with and proportionally spaced font.

Answer (score 1):

Medium-length answer: kind of.

It won't be possible AFAIK to force right-justification, but you can force a kind of left-justification by using a tab, or "\t".

If the character width of your text area will be consistent, it should be possible to be tricky with it to simulate right-justification.

For instance in theory you could use "\t" to get as close as possible to the desired position and then fill in the rest with spaces or blank characters.